# Change the behavior of the type() function on a user-created class

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, types

So I want to change how the `type()` function works on a class that I create. I'll create two classes, one "old style" class and one "new style" which inherits from `object`, to demonstrate what I mean:

```
class Foo:
    pass

class Bar(object):
    pass
```

Now I'll create an instance of each of those:

```
spam = Foo()
eggs = Bar()
```

What happens if I use the `type()` function on each of these classes?

```
>>> type(spam)
<type 'instance'>
>>> type(eggs)
<class '__main__.Bar'>
```

I'm looking for a way to alter the behavior of this so that it appears more like this:

```
>>> type(spam)
<type 'foo'>
```

I've seen many other objects do this (besides the default data types obviously). For example:

```
>>> x = iter(['a', 'b', 'c'])
>>> type(x)
<type 'listiterator'>
>>> y = (i for i in range(10))
>>> type(y)
<type 'generator'>
```

Something like this would come pretty close, but I would prefer not to have the membership dot in the middle if I can help it. (Yes, the code I am using this in will be an imported file.)

```
>>> from itertools import *
>>> z = imap(pow, (2, 3, 4), (5, 2, 4))
>>> type(z)
<type 'itertools.imap'>
```

I'm sure the answer to this question is really simple, but for whatever reason I can't figure out how to word a search query on this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What `type` returns when called with a single is the class of an object. The string you see printed there is its "representation", and it is generated by a call to `repr` for the class. itself - the `repr` is called by the interactive prompt. Python objects customize their representation  by defining a `__repr__` method.

Since you want to customize the `__repr__` of the class, and not of its instances, you have to overide the method in the class's class itself. In Python that is called `metaclass`.

The base metaclass for all Python "new style" objects is `type` itself. `type` is much more than a simple function to return an object's class - it is actually that thing: the "base metaclass" for everything. (Old style classes have a different metaclass - but them **you should not** be using old style classes for anything. At all. Seriously. Actually, you should be using Python 3 by now - but if you aren't changing, please just forget old style classes exist)

So, to customize a class's class, you create a new class inheriting from `type` itself. You will find several blog posts and documentation explaining how to do that and override `__new__`, or `__init__`. But in this case, you 
don't need to change the actual behavior of your classes cretion - just the way they are represented.

You can just do:

```
class MyType(type):
   def __repr__(cls):
       return "<type '{}'>".format (cls.__name__)

 class Foo(object):
     __metaclass__ = MyType
```

And it will work as you want. Note that I put the argument for the metaclass' `__repr__` as `cls` instead of `self` - that is jsut for semantic purposes - it will receive an "instance" of itself - but the instance is a class. It would just work if "self" was used.

And finally, that will also change how your instances are `repr`esented by default - and that represenation can get ugly. If you dislike it, just write the `__repr__` method for your class as well (not just for the metaclass) , further customizing how it renders its representation to string form.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! Yep, I already got the `__repr__` function going for the class itself. One thing though, maybe I'm getting too OCD about this: if you do `type(type(Foo()))`, you get `<class '__main__.MyType'>`. Normally `type(type(something))` gives you `<type 'type'>`. Any way to fix this to make the `Foo` class completely consistent with other data types? Thanks.